# failed to load response data request content was evicted from inspector cache

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

i am trying to get file from server that has size of(15mb) through Axios Request. showing status "200", but not sending file previewData(base64) and showing this error "failed to load response data request content was evicted from inspector cache"[image] in the preview of Network in inspect. when i get 2 or 3 MB fille that successfully retrived.

Answer (score 59):

The solution I found for capturing big responses is to copy the request and execute it by other means, such as **PowerShell** or **cURL**. From the Chrome or Firefox DevTools you can copy the request to a PowerShell, cURL or fetch command by right-clicking the request, selecting copy and then selecting your preferred execution method.

What worked best for me is copying the request as cURL command from Firefox. Chrome is giving me invalid cURL commands.

To capture the response to a file, append `> response.txt` to the cURL command.

It is also possible to select cURL as the copy method and import it into **Postman**. In Postman select File - Import - Raw text and copy the cURL command. When I tried this it did mess up the double quotes in the JSON body of a POST request so it may need some manual tweaking.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.
BTW: as of Apr 2022, Chrome provides very correct `cURL` command.
Just select the API call of your interest, right click and select *copy > copy as cURL*, then paste the content of your clipboard into the bash|zsh terminal and hit enter.

Comment: Chrome Version 100.0.4896.127 (Official Build) (64-bit) delivers flawed cURL commands. Firefox 99.0.1 (64-bit) does good job in generating the correct cURL commands.

Comment: No it should not be the accepted answer, because OP is trying to preview the body of the request not the response. This only works for the response, and copying the request in such case will also drop the body

Comment: The **Postman** option worked perfectly but only with copy as cURL(bash) in chrome

Answer (score 19):

The data exists, it's just that it doesn't show it in the cache inspector because it exceeds the maximum number of characters, you can check by saving what the variable has in a .txt file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What is the maximum number of characters and can I increase it? How can I saving the request body to a .txt file?

Answer (score 14):

The easiest way is to double click the request to load the results in a new browser window.

As others have said you can also output results to a file using your preferred method.

Comment: POST? Bearer Token? other headers?

Comment: @YasinOkumuş "copy as CURL request" FTW

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the issue resolved by **closing the dev tools of Chrome and reopening it and then refreshing the page**. This may not be the case for everyone, but resolved my issue and "failed to load response data request content was evicted from inspector cache" error gone.

Answer (score 3):

Network TAB -> right click the NAME of the API request you need -> in drop down find COPY -> in the next drop down: Copy as cURL

POSTMAN tool:
near My Workspace on left -> IMPORT -> paste your cURL -> then in responsed JSON will be there... copy and paste that into any .txt or .json or .js file

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler). It can intercept the connection between the browser and the website so you can monitor everything go between.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @shtrip 's answer, but you can do it all within Chrome dev tools:

1. Right-click the request > Copy > Copy as fetch.
2. In the dev tools Console, type `var response = await`  and then <paste> the fetch(...) that Chrome put into the clipboard, and hit enter.
3. In the console: `var text = await response.text()` and now `text` contains the response.
4. Alternatively, if you want the object of a response JSON, `var obj = await response.json()`.
5. In the console, you can type either `text` <enter> or `obj` <enter> to inspect the content of the response.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, create a .txt file and save the base64 in it, I checked that the data was sent and saved. Therefore the data was not displayed in the inspector because it exceeds the maximum size.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Dear @Community bot: but sometimes it is just "street knowledge", or "if I leaked how I knew, I would get fired."